# Sql command to attach a pic to a particular record

Tags: mysql

Okay, I'm fairly new to the world of `MySQL` but I've been able to accomplish pretty much everything I need to by following you folks and your wonderful advice.

I'm sure this may already exist somewhere and I'm unable to find it so please forgive me ahead of time if this is redundant.

I have a student/staff database I'm setting up in `MySQL`. I've been able to get all of the records to import and everything there is happy.

I'd love to be able to point a folder of pics *i.e.* `/pics/id.jpg` to the database and have it automatically find them. *I.e.*, if the user in question's `id` is `2322369`, how do I tell the pic field to point to `2322369.jpg` ?

What would be the syntax for doing this?

The name of the pictures are `id#.jpg`.

How would I tell the column with the path to use that record (person's) `id` number and append it to the proper JPEG file in the path of the pic's path field?

Thanks in advance!

Marc

Comment: search about add image as BLOB

Comment: contrary to @yossico suggestion, please always avoid storing images in the database. Database are bad in handling image/binary data, plus your database size will grow very quickly leading to a variety of issues.

Comment: I'd tend to agree with @Shujaat on this one - images and other binary data are usually better left on the server's hard drive, unless you have a specific use for storing them in the database (probably one of the only use cases I can think where this really makes sense is using linked servers, and pulling the image data across into a different server for retrieval and usage on that server, as accessing data from a linked database is less of a pain in the neck than accessing the server's filesystem in this case).

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the image, rename it to the row id of the record. So for row 2322369 the picture would be uploaded as /pics/2322369.jpg. When generating html just do this

```
<img src='/pics/{row['id']}.jpg'>
```